How many times the values are being passed in the program
main()
{
int  a = 1 ; 
printf ( "%d %d %d", a, ++a, a++ ) ;
}
 

Why it is printing 3,3,1 instead of 2,2,1?
I want to understand the output I tried reading in Let us C but I could not understand please help me understand the output as why it is incrementing twice and printing the same output twice. Basically I want to understand how many times the values are being passed

In addition to the problem with changing the same variable twice, the order of evaluation of parameters is not specified. They could be computed in any order, and it doesn't have to be consistent.

In this case the compiler decided to evaluate the param list from right to left: Put a (1) to the stack and increment a / increment a and put it (3) to the stack / put a (3) to the stack. In general the order is not specified and so it depends on the implementation.

I recommend you throw away the book Let Us C which seemingly contains obsolete, misleading and incorrect material. It fails to point out that the code has undefined behaviour, and you should spend no more time figuring out what should or should not happen.

@user141068:  The 3 arguments: a, ++a, a++ are allowed to compute simultaneously.  With multiple read/write accesses, at the same time, to a, bus faults can occur. IOWs, code can die.  Do not code this way.

We frequently encounter people who have been taught bad practices by Let Us C. The book is full of errors and misconceptions. It might just be the worst C programming book out there.
